# Retrieve updated url in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

How to get the updated url from firefox browser using selenium and Python? The below code is a very good working example of what I am trying to do. The script opens up a url, looks for the search bar in the webpage, pastes a particular product and then executes the search.

I am trying to extract the updated url after the search is completed which should be `https://www.myntra.com/avene-unisex-thermal-spring-water-50-ml` but I am getting `https://www.myntra.com/`. How can I get the required url?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

firefoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefoxOptions.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = firefoxOptions)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the home page
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

# Locate the text field to update values
text_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("desktop-searchBar")

# Clears any value already present in text field
text_field.clear()

# Updates the string in search bar
text_field.send_keys("Avene Unisex Thermal Spring Water 50 ml")
text_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

new_page = driver.current_url
print(new_page)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *url* to get changed and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.desktop-searchBar"))).send_keys("Avene Unisex Thermal Spring Water 50 ml")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.desktop-submit").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title-title")))
  print(driver.current_url)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.myntra.com/avene-unisex-thermal-spring-water-50-ml
  ```

Comment: Just curious to know why `WebDriverWait` has been used before the `driver.find_element` line.

Comment: That was my bad the extra line. Fixed it. Let me know if you have a query now.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Quite honestly, I am not sure what the `WebDriverWait` steps are doing and why it has been used twice. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: also, In the above example, is there any way to make the webdriver click on the product that was searched? I would appreciate it if you could guide me on this when you have the time.

Comment: Glad that you have raised the question. The first `WebDriverWait()` is to wait (initial page loading/html rendering) for the first desired element i.e. the _search box_ to be clickable so you can send the text. The second `WebDriverWait()` is to wait (new page/html rendering) for the next desired element i.e the `<h1>` element to be visible which will ensure the `url` have settled, so we can retrieve  the _url_ for the next steps/validation. Let me know if any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait after `text_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` to get information updated,
if you don't want waits then try to use click() method instead of send_keys